# how to create subfolder for each processed file either in informatica or shell script

Tags: shell, informatica

My informatica job creates list of files as output.

Eg: ABC_DC_IND_20161119_2875793.dat
    ABC_DC_IND_20161119_2875794.dat
    ABC_DC_IND_20161119_2875795.dat

Now each of these files need to be moved/created to respective subfolders

Name of the sub folder should be same as the file name

eg: File ABC_DC_IND_20161119_2875793.dat should be in subfolder ABC_DC_IND_20161119_2875793 and so on.

how can i create a subfolder dynamically for each of the file name and also create the file in the respective subfolder. Is it possible in informatica/ shell script.

The last number in the file name is a primary key from the source table.

Please let me know the inputs

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
set ABC_DC_IND_20161119_2875793.dat ABC_DC_IND_20161119_2875794.dat ABC_DC_IND_20161119_2875795.dat
```

So now the file names are $1, $2 and $3.
Then:

```
for i; do
  dir=${i%.dat}
  mkdir -p "$dir" || exit
  mv "$i" "$dir" || exit
done
```

That moves the files into the directories using the naming conventions you described.

Comment: Hi Micheal, the file names are just the examples. I might have N number of  such files created for each run. so in that case how do i declare the files and its location.

Comment: In the code snippet above, the filenames are also just examples -- the example names you provided. I don't have enough information about the problem you're trying to solve to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all load all files to one Directory, which will be source for below program

```
cd $SOURCEFILEDIR

ls > $TEMPFILEDIR/list.txt    

rm -rf $TGTFILEDIR

for file in $($TEMPFILEDIR/list.txt)

do

   FILENAME=$(echo ${file} | cut -d"." -f1)

   XFILENAME=$(echo ${file})


   mkdir $TGTFILEDIR/$FILENAME

   chmod 775 $TGTFILEDIR/$FILENAME



   cp $SOURCEFILEDIR/$XFILENAME $TGTFILEDIR/$FILENAME/$XFILENAME

   chmod 775 $TGTFILEDIR/$FILENAME/$XFILENAME

done


rm $TEMPFILEDIR/list.txt


return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pick up the number in your mapping using a sequencer ( I prefer db sequencer, informatica sequencer is possible depending on your deploy routine ) , and then use an expression to concatenate this multiple times into a full filepath which can be passed to the flat file's special filename port